# Deploying project using 1 click publish

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, web-deployment

I have found the credentials that I should use from my server provider, and filled out everything. Right now I am getting the error when trying to validate connection:

> Error  1   Web deployment task failed. (Could not connect to the remote computer ("www.unoeuro.com").
>
> On the remote computer, make sure that Web Deploy is installed and that the required process ("Web Deployment Agent Service") is started.
>
> Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_DESTINATION_NOT_REACHABLE.)     0   0   ProjMVC

I did install web deploy 2.0 (which is the version required by my provider). I am not sure if this is the problem though. When I have installed web deploy 2.0, will VS12 automatically know about this?

This is my first time trying to deploy a project, please let me know if you need more info. I have read MS doc, and tried to follow it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465337%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

I have no more ideas about what to try

Comment: Sounds more like something to discuss with your provider. `remote computer` is your web host's machine - so the instructions on the link and error message is really for _them_ .

Comment: @EdSF is right, or if problem is not on provider side then question is for Server Fault but not SO